# Hash table search for multiple columns in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, hashtable

I have a data with about 40M rows. There are 50 columns that I would like to extract strings from them. I have used normal data step with array to perform the task, but it took over 2 hours to finish the extraction.

I know how to use hash table in SAS for simple join or subsetting by specifying a lookup table first. However, I prefer to use regular expression to do the extraction here. The current extraction is using the codes something like below.

How can I conduct hash table search in those 50 columns in SAS without an lookup table?

```
data want;
   set have;
   array cols {*} $ col1 - col50;

   do i = 1 to dim(cols)
      if prxmatch('/F[0-9].*[123]/', cols[i])
         then output;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: Do you often get more than 1 match per row, and if so, do you need to output the whole row from the input table each time?

Comment: It's not obvious how hash objects can be applied here, but you might be able to gain some improvement via the use of parallel processing - e.g. via `proc ds2`.

Comment: If the pattern appears in each of the 50 variables do you really want to output the whole observation 50 times?  Your result set could be up to 2,000M observations.

Comment: Why do you need a hash table if you are using regex ? Do you want to track the match texts in the hash ? Do you need to know the row the match text occurred in ?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping in the regex pattern will setup the conditions needed to retrieve the match with `PRXPOSN`.  The matches can be stored in a hash that is output at the end of data set processing.

```
data _null_;
   set have end=done;
   array cols {*} $ col1 - col50;

   rxid = prxparse('/(F[0-9].*[123])/');

   if _n_ = 1 then do;
     length match $200;
     declare hash matches();
     matches.defineKey(match);
     matches.defineDone();
   end;

   do i = 1 to dim(cols)
      if prxmatch(rxid, cols[i]) then do;
        match = prxposn (rxid, 1, cols[i]);
        matches.replace();
      end;
   end;

   if done then matches.output(dataset:'want_matches');
run;
```